# Как транслитерировать имя Al?

Tags: транслитерация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно транслитерировать английское имя Al? Скажем, Al Gore — "Эл Гор" или "Ал Гор"? Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-английски звучит как /æl/, а значит, на русский слух может быть воспринято и как Эл, и как Ал — «хорошего» варианта тут нет, золотая середина отсутствует. Как чувствуете, так и пишите.

My b**a**d — [май бэд] (а не [май бад]), но keep in cont**a**ct скорее [кип ин конт**а**кт], нежели [кип ин конт**э**кт].

Заметим, что contact может произноситься с двойным ударением, то есть æ не во вполне слабой позиции.

P. S. Вообще, это называется транскрипцией. Транслитерация тут однозначна: только Ал (A соответствует А, а L соответствует Л).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93387/discussion-on-answer-by-aer----al).